# RUNSTATS ON TABLE employee - 'table not readable/accessible'

Tags: sql, db2

```
RUNSTATS ON TABLE employee 
  WITH DISTRIBUTION ON COLUMNS (empid, empname, empdept NUM_FREQVALUES 
          50 NUM_QUANTILES 100)  
          DEFAULT NUM_FREQVALUES 5 NUM_QUANTILES 10
          AND INDEXES Xempid, Xempname
```

This command is failing with message - 'table not readable/accessible' but I'm able to query the table using SELECT. Not sure what is wrong. Any pointers?

Comment: What DB engine you use? DB2?

Comment: Yes I'm using DB2. And the version is v8

Comment: You may want to post the exact error message and SQLCODE. Is this DB2 for z/OS, by chance? There was no v8 for LUW.

Answer (score 0):

try add `ALLOW READ ACCESS` to command.

you can also try:

```
GRANT CONTROL ON employee TO ...
```

Comment: if this isn't solution, write your own answer, maybe it will be helpful for someone.